How would the community know of a sin done unintentionally in Numbers 15?
In Numbers 15:22-24, it talks about the community sinning unintentionally (v22) and the community not being aware of it (v24), how would the community know to give the specific burnt, grain, and drink offering?
It's without their knowledge so unless there was a failure of something happening (Achan in Joshua 7), how would anyone know the community had sinned?  I understand that a sin committed with or without knowledge of the law is still a sin but other than some outside event occurring or not occurring, how would anyone know?
Also, since this is the community's sin, where does the offering come from?  Does the community have a flock or herd of animals to choose from for their respective offerings?  I assume if it's a personal offering, the animal comes from your flock or herd but that's just my assumption.

My interpretation would be that the sin was committed unintentionally- but later they became aware of their error.
A NT example would be that the Jewish community condemned and killed Jesus as a sinner - and he in turn prayed to the Father that they be forgiven for they don’t know what they are doing. (In this case, Jesus’ blood being the sacrifice). See Luke 23:34 for instance.
On the individual level, a Jew who participated in condemning Christ and/or his church but later converted (Paul) would have sinned unintentionally only to later learn their error.
We could extrapolate and say that if the community tried a man for murder and found him guilty based upon false testimony, and only after he was executed did they discover that the testimony was false, then that would be an instance where the community sinned unintentionally (excepting those that gave the false testimony). See Numbers 35 concerning trials for murder.
As for where animals were procured, they could come from your personal flock if you had animals. Otherwise you would purchase one. I believe animals were regularly tithed to the Levites as well - though it may have just been animal byproducts.

Possibly informing them that they had done something wrong would be one of the functions of the priest?
